# I'm having problems with the nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having soome problems with the :nth-child pseudoclass.
What I want to do is select the 9th child, and than every following 6th child.

so first 9
than 15
than 21
than 27
than 33

etc.. etc..

I thought that it should work by putting this in my css:

```
.child-div:nth-child(9n+6) p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

It didn't..

I tried al diffrent formules like 10n+6, 6+9n and so on..
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-css-nth-child)
But that didn't explain it eighter.

Does someone know why it doesn't work, can you only make formules like 4n+4 or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close to solution :

```
.child-div:nth-child(6n+9) p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y49A/1/

Answer (score 2):

That's what you need:

```
.child-div:nth-child(6n+9) p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This means it selects every sixth element starting from the ninth.

Check out this online tool if you have problems with `nth-child`:

[:nth tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
.child-div:nth-child(6n+9) p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This means every 6th item, starting at 9.

Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
.child-div p:nth-of-type(6n+9){
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Charlie74 nth of type is much better than nth child. See what Chris [says](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Comment: Well, now that you've FIXED the answer, it isn't wrong...  I wasn't concerned about your choice of nth-child vs nth-of-type.

Comment: @Charlie74 oh i misunderstood that. Thanks anyway !